# Swift Generics - Protocol does not conform to Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

I'm trying to get a container that implements a set of protocols that i pass as parameter to a function on the original container.

```
struct Container {
  let someProperty: String
  let otherProperty: String
}

// Subcontainers
protocol Base {}
protocol SomePropertyContainer: Base {
  var someProperty: String { get }
}

protocol OtherPropertyContainer: Base {
  var otherProperty: String { get }
}

extension Container: SomePropertyContainer, OtherPropertyContainer {}


// Sub Container Provisioning Protocol
protocol SubContainerProviderProtocol {
  func subContainer<T: Base>(protos: T.Type) -> T?
}

extension Container: SubContainerProviderProtocol {

  func subContainer <T: Base>(protos: T.Type) -> T? {
    return self as? T
  }
}

// Example container
let subContainerProvider: SubContainerProviderProtocol = Container(someProperty: "Why does this not work!", otherProperty: "Seriously.")
```

Getting this up and running would allow me to inject the `ContainerProviderProtocol` into consumers while giving them the possibility to specify themselves which `SubContainer` they actually want.

E.g. a class that would be interested in only the `someProperty` could look like this

```
// Example Container Provider consumer
class SomeClass {

  let subContainerProvider: SubContainerProviderProtocol

  init(subContainerProvider: SubContainerProviderProtocol) {
    self.subContainerProvider = subContainerProvider
  }

  func printSomeProperty() {
    let someProperty = subContainerProvider
      .subContainer(protos: SomePropertyContainer.self)?
      .someProperty
    print(someProperty)
  }
}

// Example call
let someClass = SomeClass(subContainerProvider: subContainerProvider)
someClass.printSomeProperty() // "Why does this not work!"
```

This solution would be incredible for dependency injection & testability.

However the restriction `T: Base` is causing the compiler error

> In argument type 'SomePropertyContainer.Protocol', 'SomePropertyContainer' does not conform to expected type 'Base'

Not specifying conformance to Base will compile, but would also allow to pass **any** type as T.

I've tried with associated types within an additional protocol etc, however have not figured it out. And while this issue is incredibly fun, I'm running out of ideas.

Possibly related to (but not exactly same) https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-55

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem: at some point you have to start working with actual types, and not just protocols. Your line:

```
func container<T: Base>(protos: T.Type) -> T?
```

is telling the compiler that you're going to give this function a type, generically `T`, that conforms to the protocol `Base`, not another protocol. You need something like this:

```
class SPC: SomePropertyContainer {
    var someProperty: String = ""
}

class SomeClass {
    let containerProvider: ContainerProviderProtocol
    init(containerProvider: ContainerProviderProtocol) {
        self.containerProvider = containerProvider
    }

    func printSomeProperty() {
        let someProperty = containerProvider
            .container(protos: SPC.self)?
            .someProperty
        print(someProperty)
    }
}
```

SPC is a type that conforms to the SomePropertyContainer protocol, which itself conforms to the Base protocol, so this is what your code is expecting.

Comment: Thank you. That's what my code seems to be expecting, but how can I make him expect a protocol instead of a class type?

Comment: I don't think you can. At some point, you have to actually pass in a type -- an object or a struct. Eventually, code that is generic must be used in specific ways.